# Umbraco 7 MVC Razor - Rendering Image (Multinode Tree Picker Script)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I've created a multinode tree picker datatype and i'm trying to list the thumbnails of a vehicle as part of the foreach loop, however i keep getting ID rendering in the src of the image, i'm having trouble getting the URL of the image.

**MVC Razor Code**

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage
@using Umbraco.Web

@*
    Macro to list nodes from a Multinode tree picker, using the pickers default settings.
    Content Values stored as xml.

    To get it working with any site's data structure, simply set the selection equal to the property which has the 
    multinode treepicker (so: replace "PropertyWithPicker" with the alias of your property).
*@

@* Lists each selected value from the picker as a link *@

<div class="featuredVehicles">
    @foreach (var id in CurrentPage.featuredVehicles.Split(','))
    {    

    @*For each link, get the node, and display its name and url*@
        var vehicleContent = Umbraco.Content(id);

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-xs-height">
            <a href="@vehicleContent.Url">

                @if (vehicleContent.HasValue("vehicleThumbnail"))
                {
                    var mediaItem = Umbraco.TypedMedia(vehicleContent.GetPropertyValue("vehicleThumbnail"));
                    <img class="featuredVehicleImg img-responsive" src="@vehicleContent.GetPropertyValue("vehicleThumbnail")" alt="@vehicleContent.Name"/>                 
                }
                else
                {            
                    <img class="comingSoon" src="http://placehold.it/650x408" alt="@vehicleContent.Name">
                }

                <strong>
                    <span class="name">@vehicleContent.Name</span>
                </strong>

                <span class="desc">@vehicleContent.GetPropertyValue("shortContent")</span>

                <span class="prx">from, <strong>&pound;@vehicleContent.vehiclePrice</strong> per day</span>

                <span class="label label-primary moreinfo">More Info</span>

            </a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**HTML**

```
<img alt="Pharmaceutical Vehicle One" src="1092" class="featuredVehicleImg img-responsive">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved;

This is the bit where the problems were being caused;

```
if (vehicleContent.HasValue("vehicleThumbnail")){                                         
                        var dynamicMediaItem = Umbraco.Media(vehicleContent.vehicleThumbnail);
                        <img src="@dynamicMediaItem.umbracoFile" alt="@dynamicMediaItem.Name"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {            
                        <img class="comingSoon" src="http://placehold.it/650x408" alt="@vehicleContent.Name">
                    }
```

Hopefully it will help someone else out :-)